# Converting an onclick event to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have an anchor tag that has an `onclick` event that was set in the original HTML document. When I execute a JavaScript routine, I add a click event listener using `addEventListener`. The problem is, the original `onclick` event seems to be removed or ignored. What can I do to ensure the `onclick` event gets executed first? (No jquery)

Comment: Using `addEventListener` doesn't magically disable inline event handler. If you can't reproduce the problem with e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ then there is nothing we can do.

Comment: This turned out to be a debugging issue. A third party framework was adding its own `onclick` that was blowing mine away, when they should have been using `addEventListener`. When mine wasn't being executed, I assumed it was the event I added causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I created an example

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#foo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('foo');
}, false);
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="foo" onclick="alert('bar')">CLICK ME!!</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzgrt8do/

Everything works fine ;)

Comment: Didn't get in time for the answer but I have another fiddle which also shows it working, after you manually add an event listener http://jsfiddle.net/79sc5o65/8/

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem the OP is describing, you should not answer that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a listener using *addEventListener* should not affect the existing listener, however you have no control over the order in which they are called. To ensure an order of existing listener then new listener, you can do something like:

```
function addListener(element, newListener) {
  var oldListener;

  if (typeof element.onclick == 'function') {
    oldListener = element.onclick;
    element.onclick = function() {
      oldListener.call(this);
      newListener.call(this);
    };

  } else {
    element.onclick = newListener;
  }
  element = null;
}
```

This works only if the existing listener is added as a property (in the HTML or by assignment), not if it's been added using *addEventListener* or IE's old *attachEvent*.

You may need something a little more complex if you need to pass parameters.